# Ruby 'each' method seemingly not working

Tags: ruby, each

I want to return the amount of vowels present in a given string argument. This is my code:

```
def count_vowels(string)
  new = string.split("")
  number_of_vowels = 0
  new.each do |letters|
    if letters = "a" || letters = "e" || letters = "i" || letters = "o" || letters = "u" ||
      numbers_of_vowels = number_of_vowels + 1
    end
  end
  number_of_vowels
end
```

For any argument, `number_of_vowels` returns `0`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please format the code properly. Badly formatted code is super-difficult to read.

Comment: edited. Sorry!!

Comment: Better! Now, what do you think that trailing `||` is doing there?

Comment: Just as a side note, Ruby has [`String#each_char`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-each_char) so you can shorten your code to just `string.each_char { |letters| ... }` and not need the `split`. Then for bonus points there's [`String.count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-count): So, `"Ruby .each method not seeming to work?".count("aeiou")` outputs `11`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check for equality with `==`. `=` just assigns.

Here - 
`if letters = "a" ||` should be `if letters == "a" ||`.

Same for the rest.

---

Working code -

```
def count_vowels(string)
  new = string.split("")
  number_of_vowels = 0 
  new.each {|letters| number_of_vowels += 1 if letters == "a" || letters == "e" || letters =="i" || letters == "o" || letters == "u"}
  number_of_vowels
end
```

Demo [here](https://repl.it/KN24/6).

Comment: changed it to ==, but it seems that i'm still getting a return of 0.  Thanks for the quick reply, really appreciate it.

Comment: @Stevecane Check out updated answer. Added the working code.

Comment: `i = 0; collection.each { |e| i += 1 if ... }; i` is such a common pattern that Ruby has a method for it: [`Enumerable#count`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-count)

Comment: Right, I was trying to post a solution including only as much of OP's code as possible, without introducing other/better functions.

Answer (score 2):

There are three issues in your code.

First, you have a typo in the variable `number_of_vowels` within the loop. There you increment the counter to `numbers_of_vowels` but never use that variable (with plural `numbers`) again. Instead, you return `number_of_vowels` (with singular `number`) that still is `0`.

Second, `=` in `letters = "a"` assigns `"a"` to the variable `a` what would return *truish* all the time. Use `==` instead to compare if two values are equal.

Third, there is an orphan `||` at the end of the `if` condition. What leads the following line be part of the condition. Because the first clause already returns *truish* the calculation is never evaluated.

This is how a fixed version might look like:

```
def count_vowels(string)
  new = string.split("")
  number_of_vowels = 0 

  new.each do |letters|
    if letters == "a" || letters == "e" || letters == "i" || letters == "o" || letters == "u" 
      number_of_vowels = number_of_vowels + 1
    end 
  end 

  number_of_vowels
end
```

Furthermore, you might want to simplify your code a bit:

```
# Appending an `i` to this regexp would enable case-insensitive
# matching and would find upper-case characters too.
VOWELS = /[aeiou]/

def count_vowels(string)
  string.scan(VOWELS).size
end
```

Comment: `numbers_of_vowels` and `number_of_vowels` – spot the difference :-)

Comment: @Stefan: Thank you, I missed that detail.

Comment: I agree. But I see no benefit in changing that in my answer. If I changed the OP's code to use common Ruby idioms (like `Array#include?` instead of the conditions or `+=`) then I would ultimately end up with my second version...

Comment: @spickermann : what about Capital vowel? it won't count, instead of scan, can use `String#count` as I answered

Comment: @GaganGami The OP didn't ask to count upper-case character too. But that would be simple to add. just change the regexp from `/[aeiou]/` to `/[aeiou]/i`